# How to use padStart in a JS loop to output a triangle of Xs?

Tags: javascript

I am supposed to create a triangle of Xs as depicted in the link by using padString [image of 20 lines of Xs starting with one X and incrementing by one X for each additional line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHOlH.png)

The hint they gave was that I am supposed to use something like...

```
let str = "";
str = str.padStart(i,”x”); // i is the loop counter
```

What I have so far is this...

```js
let xShape = "x";
for (let counter = 0; counter <= 20; counter = counter + 1) {
  xShape = xShape + "x"
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  xShape.padStart(xShape, "x");
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

But that doesn't write out 20 lines of Xs starting with the first line having only one X with each new line having an additional X. It only writes the last line of 20 Xs. How do I get it to write all 20 lines? I am a beginner, and am doing this to learn. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

padStart takes the string passed to it, and pads the beginning with the first argument as many times as the second argument.

So you can add it to a loop and just pass it an empty string so it will always have an empty starting point.

```js
let xShape = "";
for (let counter = 0; counter <= 20; counter++) {
  xShape += "".padStart(counter, "x") + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xShape;
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to *collect* output lines in the loop somehow. But your use of `padStart` is also wrong: the first argument should not be a string, but a number. It should actually be your loop counter.

```js
let lines = [];
for (let counter = 1; counter <= 20; counter = counter + 1) {
  lines.push("".padStart(counter, "x"));
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = lines.join("<br>");
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Note that the method `repeat` is more natural here:

```js
let lines = [];
for (let counter = 1; counter <= 20; counter = counter + 1) {
  lines.push("x".repeat(counter));
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = lines.join("<br>");
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

In a more functional approach:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
    Array.from({length:20}, (_, counter) => "x".repeat(counter+1))
         .join("<br>");
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```